# Django: Setting values of certain attributes in the database using views?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I have a form in my application which has a hidden form field, the value of which I want to set in my corresponding view after submitting the form.

forms.py

```
  class EvangelizedForm(forms.ModelForm):
        first_name = forms.CharField(help_text="First Name")
        last_name = forms.CharField(help_text="Last Name")
        email = forms.CharField(help_text="Email ID")
        mobile_no = forms.CharField(help_text="Mobile number")
        twitter_url = forms.CharField(help_text="Twitter URL")
        twitter_followers = forms.CharField(widget = forms.HiddenInput())   #Hidden form field

class Meta:
        model = Evangelized
        fields = ('first_name','last_name', 'twitter_url', 'email', 'mobile_no')
```

models.py

```
class Evangelized(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField()
    mobile_no = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length = 10, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^\w{10}$', message='Mobile number should be strictly of 10 digits.')])
    twitter_url = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=128)
    twitter_followers = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
```

views.py

```
def fillform(request):
    follower_count = '250'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EvangelizedForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.fields['twitter_followers'] = follower_count
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            form.errors
    else:
        #form = EvangelizedForm()
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            form = EvangelizedForm(initial={'first_name': request.user.first_name,
                                                'twitter_url': 'https://twitter.com/' + request.user.username,
                                                    'last_name': request.user.last_name})
        else:
            form = EvangelizedForm()    

    context = RequestContext(request,
                           {'request': request,
                            'user': request.user, 'form':form})    

    #return render(request, 'rango/fillform.html', {'form': form, 'context_instance':context})  
    return render_to_response('rango/fillform.html',
                             context_instance=context)
```

Basically, I'm trying to set the value of `twitter_followers` (which is a hidden form field in forms.py) in my `index` view, by:

```
follower_count = '250'
..
..
form.fields['twitter_followers'] = follower_count
```

By doing this, I'm expecting the value of `'twitter_followers'` in the database after submitting the form to be `'250'`. However, this approach doesn't seem to be working.

What's the right way to set values to certain attributes in the database manually using views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it on the model instance, which is the result of `form.save`. That's the main reason for the `commit` argument in the first place.

```
if form.is_valid()
    obj = form.save(commit=True)
    obj.twitter_follower = follower_count
    obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the save method of the form, with something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs)
    twitter_followers = kwargs.pop('twitter_followers', 0)
    self.instance.twitter_followers = twitter_followers
    super(Evangelized, self).save(args, kwargs)
```

And then in the view just have to call in this way:

```
form.save(twitter_followers=250)
```